# Visual Studio 2012 Breakpoint to modify a value?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2012, vs-extensibility

I am looking for solution to modify variable at breakpoint hit in Visual Studio 2012

Previous Visual Studio versions it can be done using macros

e.g [Visual Studio Breakpoint Macro to modify a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3868810/visual-studio-breakpoint-macro-to-modify-a-value)

Can anyone help me about how to achieve that in VS 2012 ,Visual Studio 2012 doesnt support Macros , so i am not getting that option

Comment: I'm curious what the use-case of this would be.

Comment: You can run old macros code with Visual Commander http://vlasovstudio.com/visual-commander/